# Phonegap - How to change default icon?

Tags: cordova, icons

Sorry if I repost the question, but really I can't get out of this.
I'm using Phonegap 3.4.0 via CLI. I'm trying to set the icon of my app following the docs on Phonegap site, but nothing works!

This is my situation:

In folder myproject/www/res/icons/android/ I put the following images icon-36-ldpi.png, icon-48-mdpi.png, icon-72-hdpi.png and icon-96-xhdpi.png.

In folder myproject/www/ I put config.xml with the following instructions:

```
<icon src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png"   gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<icon src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="mdpi" />
<icon src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png"   gap:platform="android"    gap:density="hdpi" />
<icon src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png"  gap:platform="android"    gap:density="xhdpi" />
```

But nothing happens! I know that config.xml is not considered using CLI, but how can I set the icons via CLI??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, actually I resolved this problem putting drawable folder with icons & splash screens directly into platform/android/res. And it works.